# Comparison operator "no match" error

Tags: c++

I have searched the site for something similar, however the other posts on "no match for operator" errors do not help in my situation.

I have a struct node in the beginning, and then the following piece of code:

Function end() returns a type node. Therefore the statement op != end(OPEN) should resolve just fine, however I am getting the error: no match for 'operator!=' in '*op != end(OPEN)'

I am using G++ compiler. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I have been trying just about anything for hours... Thanks

```
typedef struct node {   
bool h1;
bool w1;
bool h2;
bool w2;
bool h3;
bool w3;
bool b;

int operation;
int iterator;

node *parent;};

node end ( list l ) {
node *n;

return *n;}

bool exists ( node *s, list OPEN, list CLOSED ){
node op;
node cl;
op = begin(OPEN);
cl = begin(CLOSED);
int x;

for(; op != end(OPEN); x++)
{
    if( (*(*op)) == (*s) )
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a comparison operator for your `node` type:

```
bool operator!=( const node& lhs, const node& rhs );
```

#### Edit:

Just define an equality comparison, then define inequality in terms of that:

```
bool operator==( const node& lhs, const node& rhs ) {
    return ...; // whatever
}

bool operator!=( const node& lhs, const node& rhs ) {
    return !( lhs == rhs );
}
```

Also, these don't have to be member functions, unless you access private members.

Comment: See I was using this and everything was fine but it was causing strange behavior at other parts of the program. For some reason it wouldn't allow me to overload the operator for a second time...

Comment: i.e. I needed to also have bool operator==( const node& rhs ); but it wouldn't allow me to do that.

Comment: Why do you need to overload it the second time?

Comment: Because further down in my code I had also if (op == blah blah) and that also needed overloading, but maybe I'm wrong since now that I've fixed the rest it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
op != end(OPEN)
```

You are trying to compare two `node` structures but there is no comparison operator defined for them.

I'm not sure what your code even does. Are you trying to compare the structure values or just the pointers? And what is the `end` function supposed to do? Right now, it causes undefined behaviour because you are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. I was actually trying to compare the pointers, not the values they point to. This helps a lot, I think it solves the problem!

Comment: @George Violris: Make sure you fix your `end` function too. What were you expecting it to return?

Comment: The end function is a dummy, it was just to show my point here as it was too long to output everything on here. The end function actually finds the last node on a list and returns a pointer to the node. It works for all other purposes of the program (though not as you see it here). Thanks a lot!